# Regex for Text which should eliminate (\ < " > <>) and when there is space it should accept value in double quotes

Tags: java, regex

(`?=[^\<"><>])(?=([A-Za-z0-9])*`)
 I have come up with this **regex** but it is accepting the sentence without double quotes, but I want that when there is sentence it should be in double quotes and it should not accept `\ < " > <>` these special characters

Input: harry potter
output: accepted
expected: harry potter should only be accept within double quotes because there is space between the words

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question.

Comment: Use [edit] option (it is placed under the tags) to clarify your question. Include example of input and expected result with logic which you used to create that result.

Comment: like if I enter harry potter than it should be accepted in double quotes but now it is accepting without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work :

```
^(?:"[^<>"]+"|[^<>"\s]+)$
```

It matches full strings that follow one of these two formats :

- starts with a quote, ends with a quote, without quotes or <> in the middle
- no quotes, <> or spaces

Comment: yes it is accepting the values as per need and if there is a space double quote is mandatory.

Comment: but I also want all the special character except \ < " <> to be accepted in double quotes and not without quotes